Given MAC address, how to tell if interface is wifi
Is there a way, on the command line, given a MAC address of a local network interface on the current machine (e.g. 01:23:45:67:89:ab), to determine if that interface is WiFi vs wired?
I'm trying to do this in a shell script.

Besides the quirk that their method (I think) could also report virtual wireless interfaces as real wireless interfaces (which again I think should be easily solvable just by inspecting /sys/class/net/*/ a bit further) @PhilippWendler has an even simpler way down below that involves simply inspecting /sys/class/net, which I believe it's as simple as it can get, so please check out their answer as well.

Another way using lshw + jq; it should be fairly robust as it relies on lshw for detection and on jq for parsing.
This assumes bash (because of the &>/dev/null redirection; &>/dev/null could be changed to >/dev/null 2>&1 for use with non bash-compatible shells and POSIX compliance):
{
    LANG=C lshw -json -class network | 
    jq -e --arg serial '01:23:45:67:89:ab' '.[] | select(.description == "Wireless interface" and .serial == $serial)'
} &>/dev/null && echo yes || echo no

This will echo "yes" only in case a "network" device is classified as a "Wireless interface" and its MAC address is "01:23:45:67:89:ab"; naturally this would best be refactored into a function for ease of use:
is_wireless_adapter() {
    {
        LANG=C lshw -json -class network | 
        jq -e --arg serial "$1" '.[] | select(.description == "Wireless interface" and .serial == $serial)'
    } &>/dev/null && echo yes || echo no
}

Usage:
is_wireless_adapter <MAC_ADDRESS>

% ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp100s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:21:0b:3d:b7:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:d0:45:66:b0:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp0s20f3
    inet 192.168.1.3/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
    valid_lft 86077sec preferred_lft 86077sec
    inet6 fe80::1c63:81ea:f46a:b3db/64 scope link noprefixroute 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
% is_wireless_adapter '48:21:0b:3d:b7:87'
no
% is_wireless_adapter 'e0:d0:45:66:b0:c5'
yes

You could also remove the echos in order to have the function return a status code and in order to be able to perform some different logic on it:
is_wireless_adapter() {
    {
        LANG=C lshw -json -class network | 
        jq -e --arg serial "$1" '.[] | select(.description == "Wireless interface" and .serial == $serial)'
    } &>/dev/null
}


Nice! And much better than mine. This should be more robust by far.

@terdon By technicalities probably yes, although for any practical purpose, I would say your iwonfig way at least just wouldn't break unless in the future someone drastically changes the way iwconfig works / outputs stuff (something my solution is also susceptible to), and it has the advantage of being so simple that you can just type it in going off of memory. But yeah probably lshw would be better in case you want something a bit more reliable and set in stone such as a permanent function that you plan on using often

Try mac=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff; iwconfig 2>/dev/null | grep -w "$mac" && echo "Is wireless" || echo "Is not wireless" and you will be told it is wireless because the output of iwconfig contains brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff. Your solution handles this correctly.

@terdon Fair enough, "any practical purpose" minus checking a broadcast address :) All I mean is that your solution has definetly merit, too, as it's very simple and useful 99% of the times

Thanks for this, good idea. Do you think the string "Wireless interface" can be relied on to be consistent? One other thing I noticed is wireless interfaces have a configuration.wireless key, too, so I'm wondering if checking for the presence of that (or also capabilities.wireless) would be even more robust or if it doesn't matter.

@JasonC Yeah it should be reliable as long as you don't remove the LANG=C at the start, I put that in exactly because of that, otherwise it could be localized differently depending on the system; about configuration.wireless: what if the device is in some sort of non-configured state? Would the outer configuration key even exist (albeit maybe missing some sub-keys / all of them)? I feel like without knowing for sure the ins an outs of checking configuration under different circumnstances, checking description should be way more reliable

It seems quite easy to extract this information from /sys without any special tools:
for i in /sys/class/net/*/; do 
  [[ 01:23:45:67:89:ab = $(cat "$i/address") && -d "$i/wireless" ]] && 
    echo "Device is wireless"
done


Besides the very small nitpick that this would probably report as a "wireless device" both real wireless devices and virtual wireless devices, this approach is the best and simpler (in fact I think this may be exactly how lshw polls for hardware info), but I'm sure even the small "virtual devices" quirk could be resolved by further inspecting the contents of /sys/class/net/*/ (for example I see a device directory inside my "real" interfaces, perhaps checking for the existance of that directory is all there is to tell apart a virtual device from a real one?)

@kos I didn't know that virtual wireless devices exist, but at least my virtual tun and virbr devices do not have a device symlink, so yes, this seems likely a possible way.

so a "generic" list of interfaces could be: for d in /sys/class/net/*/; do virt_phys=$( [ -d "$d/device" ] && echo "physical" || echo "virtual?" ); type=$( [ -d "$d/wireless ] && echo "wireless" || echo "other_type" ); printf "Address %s for %s is %s ( %s )\n" "$(cat $d/address)"   "$d" "$virt_phys" "$type" ; done ? # note: I can't test right now... may need much further exploration of the content of /sys/class/net/* to be more acurate and useful?

Kos's answer is a better way, please use that. I am relying on naive text parsing here so if, by some weird chance, the string of the MAC address appears in some other part of the outputs I parse, I will incorrectly claim it is a wireless device. For example, if you search for ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff in the output of ip addr, you will find it, but that isn't a valid MAC of an existing wireless device. Kos's answer can handle this gracefully.

Here's one way, but I am not sure how robust it is:
mac=01:23:45:67:89:ab
iwconfig 2>/dev/null | grep -w "$mac" && echo "Is wireless" || echo "Is not wireless"

The iwconfig command only shows information for wireless cards, so if your MAC isn't in its output, then it shouldn't be from a wireless device.
Alternatively, you could do something more roundabout like getting the device name from /proc/net/wireless and then checking the MAC in the output of ip. Like this:
device=$(awk -F":" '!/\|/{print $1}' /proc/net/wireless )
ip addr show dev "$device" |
  grep -wq "$mac" && echo "Is wireless" || echo "Is not wireless"

On my system, /proc/net/wireless looks like this:
$ cat /proc/net/wireless
Inter-| sta-|   Quality        |   Discarded packets               | Missed | WE
 face | tus | link level noise |  nwid  crypt   frag  retry   misc | beacon | 22
wlp9s0: 0000   40.  -70.  -256        0      0      0      0   1249        0

So the awk command is using : as the field separator, so that the first field, $1, will be wlp9s0 and the !/\|/ ensures we only print on lines that don't contain | so we only get device lines and not headeres. Next, the output of ip addr looks like this:
$ ip addr show dev wlp9s0
3: wlp9s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:cd:0d:57:0a:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.57/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp9s0
       valid_lft 846797sec preferred_lft 846797sec
    inet6 2a02:8012:de3:1:929a:6dd0:d7df:53b1/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 5503sec preferred_lft 1903sec
    inet6 2a02:8012:de3:1:b9ec:8f1a:9da8:2c47/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6907sec preferred_lft 3307sec
    inet6 fe80::929a:6dd0:d7df:53b1/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

So if that output contains your MAC, you can assume it is indeed from a wireless device. Kinda. If you set your MAC to be ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Of course, you might have more than one wireless device, so this might be a better option to cover that possibility:
devices=( $(awk -F":" '!/\|/{print $1}' /proc/net/wireless ) )
for device in "${devices[@]}"; do
  ip addr show dev "$device" |
   grep -wq "$mac" && echo "Is wireless" || echo "Is not wireless"
done


On systems using NetworkManager, you could consider using nmcli to get the device MAC (known as HWADDR) and TYPE:
$ nmcli -e no -g GENERAL.HWADDR,GENERAL.TYPE dev show
08:00:27:8E:46:AB
ethernet

BC:AE:C5:7D:A0:AA
wifi

08:00:27:A7:C4:90
ethernet

00:00:00:00:00:00
loopback

It doesn't appear to allow directly polling of devices by MAC, so post processing is still required - for example with awk
$ nmcli -e no -g GENERAL.HWADDR,GENERAL.TYPE dev show | 
    awk -vRS= -v mac='BC:AE:C5:7D:A0:AA' '$1 == mac {print $2}'
wifi

$ nmcli -e no -g GENERAL.HWADDR,GENERAL.TYPE dev show | 
    awk -vRS= -v mac='08:00:27:A7:C4:90' '$1 == mac {print $2}'
ethernet

If you want to turn that into some kind of indicator function, you could do something like this:
$ declare -f -p isWifi
isWifi () 
{ 
    nmcli -e no -g GENERAL.HWADDR,GENERAL.TYPE dev show | awk -vRS= -v mac="$1" '
    $1 == mac {found = 1; wifi = ($2 == "wifi"); exit} 
    END {exit(found == 1 ? (wifi == 1 ? 0 : 1) : 2)}
  '
}

Then
$ isWifi BC:AE:C5:7D:A0:AA; echo "$?"
0

(MAC BC:AE:C5:7D:A0:AA found and IS wifi)
$ isWifi 08:00:27:A7:C4:90; echo "$?"
1

(MAC 08:00:27:8E:46:AB found but is NOT wifi)
$ isWifi FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF; echo "$?"
2

(MAC FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF not found).

@kos funnily enough I wrote !wifi originally - but somehow it didn't feel idiomatic - I like your first suggestion though and have incorporated it

@kos fwiw I still think your answer is better - at least, I'm assuming nmcli only works if the device has a working driver, whereas lshw should probe right down to the hardware

Yeah I agree, too much golfing there, wifi == 1 ? 0 : 1 is much clearer. I'm unsure about nmcli but I'd wager you're correct there too (I'm not sure what would be managed exactly without a working driver first...)
